# how to fix error when url is directly entered with no search keywords?

Tags: php, error-handling

I am creating small search engine for job portal. I used following code for searching.

```
<form method="get" action="search.php">
 <input type="text" name="keyword">
 <input type="text" name="location">
</form>
```

when I search it sends input by url and displays the results. 

e.g : url:  localhost/jobportal/search.php?keyword=php&location=India

But if I directly open the page by entering url : "localhost/jobportal/search.php" in browser, it shows following error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: keyword in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\search\index.php on line 384
Notice: Undefined index: location in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobportal\search\index.php on line 385
```

I know why this error is occurring I only need to know how to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check if they exists. Use `empty`. -

```
if(!empty($_GET['keyword'])) {
    // use value
}

if(!empty($_GET['location'])) {
    // use value
}
```

`empty()` will check if it is `set` and the `value` is not `null` or `false`.

Comment: answer is right but It should be in a single condition.

Comment: Yes. But it is not sure how OP is building the condition! If both are compulsory the simply using `&&` will do the job.